# Panda dataframe replace() method for row numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace some values in a column with a specific value using the row numbers list of the required values as an array like following array.Can I use `dataframe.replace()` for that?

```
row_numbers = [  4,   7,  15,  18,  49,  60,  78,  80]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loc`

```py
df.loc[row_numbers, 'col'] = 3
```

in case your index is not number

```py
df['col'].iloc[row_numbers] = 3
```